# Not Optimum Mode: Recommended Mode: 1280x1024 60Hz

Tags: server, grub2, display-resolution, nomodeset

I have a problem I can't seem to fix.

I have acquired an old server: 
- Intel Xeon CPU 3.20 GHz
- 4 Gigs RAM
- 250 Gig HDD
- Generic VGA (I think - I can find no way of checking)

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server (a very basic install without any of the extras). I used the "nomodeset" option by pressing F6 at the time of setup.

When I boot up, I get the Intel Server Board splash screen... and that's it. I don't get the grub menu. A bouncing "screen saver" type of message appears telling me: "Not Optimum Mode: Recommended Mode: 1280x1024 60Hz" and I can't get any further - ie: I never get to the terminal command prompt.

I thought nomodeset would help, but it hasn't.
I have found a promising solution by changing the GRUB_GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub to 1280x1024, but, as I've mentioned, I can't get to the command line.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: I have discovered that after a shutdown/restart (not reboot) I can get access by pressing the ESC key repeatedly. Changing the GRUB_GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub to 1280x1024 did not help.

Comment: Did you try booting from a live disk and editing that file?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand. I'm running Ubuntu Server... can I boot from the installation disc? Also, I assume you mean the /etc/default/grub file? I did edit it on my system...

Comment: If you did edit it ... What is the problem now

Comment: I changed the GRUB_GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub to 1280x1024 and ran sudo update-grub. The problem persists,

Comment: Another issue is that pressing the Esc key only lets me into the system randomly. ie: it never seems to work on a reset and only sometimes works after a shutdown.

Comment: Did you run sudo update-grub in live DVD?

Comment: I ran it on my installed system the last time I managed to get in.

Comment: What I'd like to do is use whatever driver ubuntu uses to install the system!

Comment: I have just managed to get back into the system for the 1st time in about 24 hours. I have no idea how. I have ensured that GRUB_GFXMODE is set to 1280x1024. When I rebooted I got the bouncing error message again!

Comment: Is there no way I can use the driver that Ubuntu uses when it installs the system? I'm running server so I don't need fancy graphics.

Comment: AMD Rage XL PCI rev27...

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the AMD Rage XL PCI (rev27) video card and the solution is to get a new card.